# Unable to Export Detail Row in Jquery Datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am trying to export the whole datatables with detail row (this is another data table inside data table) and unable to export it once. What could be the best way to do it ?

Thanks.

Comment: Please check this Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @beaver, can i help with question ?